# Does the Anonymous access protect Realtime Database from access outside of my application package?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am going to use Firebase Realtime Database. I have found that there exists very flexible authentication system, but I'd like to give read-access to my Android application package only.

I use FCM and it's model is almost clean: I understand, that my API account + application package name = authorization credentials on Google (& Firebase?) side. In this way I understand, that there is impossible to get token outside of my application package, signed by my cert.

Regarding Firebase Realtime Database I suppose the same behavior for Anonymous access model. Am I right?

Comment: Anonymous access still requires an auth token resulting from a successful authentication with the Firebase Auth service.

Comment: Arthur, thanks! Yes sure, a client in Anonymous access becomes its token generated by Firebase Auth and this token can be converted into registered user. But does Firebase perform any check of package of a client before giving him this  token? 

In other words, is it possible to get anonymous token outside of application package registered in Firebase or Google console?

Comment: No the request to authenticate even anonymously must have an appropriate package and sha1 attached to the request.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, Arthur! It seems that I understand it right. I think that so-called fingerprint should be added to package setting in console to let it work properly. Because in case of Cloud Messaging I have built app-debug (unsigned) and it were registering without problem. I suppose that in this way I could use any package name and get registration token for this package. I suggest that if the package had fingerprint - it couldn't be possible. Well, I will try to check it out next time.